# Create a local variable when a function is called

Tags: function, variables, lua, set, local

I am writing a mod for a game, and I have a script that I cannot edit. The part I am concerned goes a little bit something like this:

```
--Script A (cannot change this part)

local f_loadup = true
local function load_FPx(a,b)
    return _G.fpxTin(),a..b
end


--Script B (I can edit this.)

function _G.fpxTin()
-- Here I need to be able to set the local variable of f_loadup in Script A
-- to false when the function is called by Script A.
end
```

When Script A calls load_FPx, I need the global function that it also runs (_G.fpxTin) to set Script A's local variable (f_loadup) to false.

Comment: Isn't this very similar to the question you just asked?

Comment: Yes, @RyanStein but I cannot figure out how to get f_loadup; it's not inside of the load_FPx function.

Comment: Why do you need to change it if it's not used?

Comment: Ryan's solution to your other question should work for this too. Note that doing what you're asking is usually considered bad taste -- the `debug` library isn't really meant to be used like this because it lets you do things that can break basic language semantics. It's not clear why you cannot change `script A`. If `f_loadup` is really meant to be changed by your own `script B` then why isn't it made accessible in some way to begin with? Forcing access like you're doing here would break encapsulation.

Comment: Where exactly is the other question... the one with the answer? I'm looking into something similar as well.